# How do I complete Prince of Persia Retro (iPhone/iPad) level 2?

Tags: ios, prince-of-persia

I am upset about Prince of Persia Retro level 2 ending.

When I go all the way to the left of the exit door, there is a huge jump to the button to open the door. I've tried the following to solve it:

- I can make that jump with a run, no problem. But, to get back, there is no room to run.
- When I try to run, I can't make the jump and fall to death.
- When I carefully step to the ledge and jump without running, I don't have enough momentum and I fall to death.

I can't find a way to complete it. What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to press the "move cautiously" button and the end of the jump in order to hold onto the edge. You end up hanging, after that you can pull yourself up with "up".

This used to be the old "action" button, which actually was the whole screen.

Comment: Thanks. Both answers were correct, but I’m marking this as the answer because it's more detailed/accurate.

Comment: @Jaanus: Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but PoP retro is a perfect port of the original, which means that you will be interested in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHRRznZ_cnI).  I think you're referring to 3:10, but to be safe, watch from about 3 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to back up to the edge of the activation plate, turn around, run left the  turn right so he slides into the turn.  Then, ASAP, press jump and pray.  He gets an extra foot down.  Come on people, think outside the scroll.